# Does the named return slice need to be initialized with make in Go?

Tags: go, append, slice

Suppose a function such as:

```golang
func returnNamedSlice(num int) (s []int)
```

I am able to do the following directly in the code, as if s was already made.

```golang
s = append(s, 5)
```

But if I don't do the above (`append` operation), then `s` is always `nil` and the returned `s` is also `nil`.

Why this design? This seems very inconsistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The named return slice is initialized to nil. The following statement works because a nil slice is handled the same as an empty slice by the `append` function.

```
 s = append(s, 5)
```

Nil slices are handled the same as empty slices because the length and capacity of a nil slice are defined to be zero, the same as an empty slice.

The feature is unrelated to named return values. Here's a demonstration without return values:

```
  var x []int           // x is a nil slice of int
  fmt.Println(x)        // prints []
  fmt.Println(x == nil) // prints true
  x = append(x, 5)      // x is slice with one element, 5
  fmt.Println(x)        // prints [5]
  fmt.Println(x == nil) // prints false
```

A confusing point when examining these features is that the `fmt` package prints nil slices and empty slices with the same representation, `[]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can append items to nil slice too, no matter it's nil or not.

Look at the example below:

```
package main

import "log"

func main() {
    a := a() // no matter it returns nil 
    log.Println("Is a nil: ", a == nil)
    a = append(a, 1) // you can append items to nil slice
    log.Println(a)
    //
    b := b()
    b = append(b, 2)
    log.Println(b)
}

func a() (s []int) {
    return
}

func b() (s []int) {
    s = append(s, 5)
    return
}
```

And the result:

```
2022/06/19 09:52:02 Is a nil:  true
2022/06/19 09:52:02 [1]
2022/06/19 09:52:02 [5 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Any named-return-variable ("result parameter", as [the spec](https://go.dev/ref/spec) calls it) in Go is "pre-initialized" to the appropriate zero value, exactly the same as any locally-defined variable that has no initializer:

```
var i int
var f float64
var s string
```

`i` is zero (integer), `f` is zero (`0.0`, float64), and `s` is "zero" (empty string `""`).  So it is with your function:

```
func returnNamedSlice(num int) (s []int) {
    // ... code here ...
    return
}
```

At the top of the function, where the `// code here` code goes, `s` is initialized to "zero", i.e., `[]int(nil)`: `nil` as converted to `[]int`.  This is described under the [Return statements](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Return_statements) section of the Go spec.

You must *set* `s` to some *non-nil value* to return some non-nil value.  You *do not have to use `append`* but it's pretty standard to append to the appropriately typed `nil` since that makes it easy to build up a list in a loop or with a series of `if` tests or whatever:

```
if conditionA {
    s = append(s, 42)
}
if conditionB {
    s = append(s, 6, 9)
}
```

But:

```
if conditionC {
    s = []int{3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9}
}
```

will work too.

Whatever `s` is set to in the end, that's what it will hold at return time.  Note that:

```
return someval
```

means (1) assign the value *to* `s`, and then (2) return (in that order).  If a deferred function then calls `panic` *and* there's a panic handler that traps the panic and uses `s` and/or assigns a *new* value to `s`, this matters; see [the Defer statement examples in the spec](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Defer_statements).